# How to get Create Account Link in Liferay 7 or DXP form themeDisplay

Tags: liferay, liferay-7, liferay-theme, liferay-dxp

In Liferay 6 it was possible to get various types of links, for example you could get CreateAccount link from themeDiplay by using `themeDisplay.getURLCreateAccount().toString()`. Check this [link](https://docs.liferay.com/portal/6.0/javadocs/com/liferay/portal/theme/ThemeDisplay.html#getURLCreateAccount())

Recently I've migrated to Liferay 7. In my custom theme when I am working with `.ftl` files I'd like to have `create account link` but I can't find any suitable methods for it. Although you can find `getURLSignIn()` and `getURLSignOut`. Check this [link](https://docs.liferay.com/portal/7.0/javadocs/portal-kernel/com/liferay/portal/kernel/theme/ThemeDisplay.html#getURLSignIn--)

Is there any chance to find a create account url by themeDisplay? If not what should I do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For theme freemaker template, you can use following.

```
<#assign plid = layout.getPlid()>
<#assign createAccountURL = portletURLFactory.create(request,"com_liferay_login_web_portlet_LoginPortlet",plid,"RENDER_PHASE")>
${createAccountURL.setParameter("mvcRenderCommandName", "/login/create_account")}
${createAccountURL.setParameter("p_p_state", "maximized")}
${createAccountURL.setParameter("p_p_mode", "view")}

<a href="${createAccountURL}"> Create Account </a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use action commands in Liferay 7 to call the create account in the JSP

Example :

https://dev.liferay.com/develop/tutorials/-/knowledge_base/7-0/mvc-action-command

Comment: the question is related to theme development, your answer is not